# Word problems based on probability theory

Tags: probability

> A player plays a game against a machine. At each round he deposits a coin the machine and flips another coin. The probability of heads appearing is $\frac 13$. If heads comes up, the coin deposited is received back along with an extra coin. If tails comes up, that coin is lost. Find the probability that the player loses all his coins by the thirteenth round or earlier. The player starts with 10 coins.

I don’t know the exact method to do it, but here is my try.

I think all cases have to be manually sorted. I found a few ie. he gets all tails for ten continues attempts, or he gets a heads in the first attempt and then gets tails until all coins are exhausted, or gets 2 heads and then all tails.

I don’t know if there are any more than this. Also is there a methodical way to solve it, by using binomial distribution or something of that kind?

Comment: How many coins does the player start with?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews 10 coins. Forgot to add it

Comment: Better put it in the question, too.

Comment: Is P(head) = $1/3$, or is is it a typo for $1/2$ ?

Comment: @trueblueanil it’s $\frac 13$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that If the player wins 2 or more games he is able to play until the 14-th round.
Therefore the described result is possible only if he wins no game or wins 1 out of the first 10 games and loses all the others.

The probability of this event is

> $$\left(\frac23\right)^{10}+10 \frac13\left(\frac23\right)^{11}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The final round cannot be the 11th round, nor the  13th round, because you are left with an odd number of coins after an odd number of rounds.

So you only have to consider $10$ and $12$ rounds. You’ve already got the probability of $10$ rounds.